# Do you say "get away with <somebody>"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, word-in-context

From [Definition of get away with phrasal verb from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get-away?q=get+away+):

> get away with something
>
> ​1. to steal something and escape with it
>
> - Thieves got away with computer equipment worth $30 000.

## Question

Do you use 'get away with' with a person? For example, can you say the following in a situation when someone committed kidnapping?:

- He got away with my son.

Comment: That is going to depend on the culture. It will mean something quite different in England to what it would mean in the US, for example.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference of meanings that you said?

Comment: Thanks. So 'got away with' might have different meanings depending on the culture and the context. Is the above sentence indicating kidnapping I've written on my post one of possible usage, or it isn't used that way in England?

Comment: You certainly wouldn't use _got away with_  in connection with kidnapping _unless_ the kidnapper had had to escape with their captive (see the definition!).